# startIndex cannot be larger than length of string when I try to import a Dimension table in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dimensions

I am trying to import a dimension table into my SSAS project. When I right click `Dimensions` and use the wizard to add a new dimension in Solution Explorer, I get the error

> startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex

rendering me unable to import the table.

My table have the properties

```
Article varchar(50)
Description nvarchar(50)
ProductCategory varchar(12)
ProductGroup nvarchar(50)
Supplier varchar(5)
```

I created the dimension table using SSIS with a simple OLE DB source from variable, where I had a Query to import data from different databases, which I then connected to an OLE DB Destination creating my dimension table.

I used the dimension earlier in my project, but I removed it to readd it with all columns taken (previously I only took the Key as a column in the table by mistake). Then I could have it imported. Now I can't even import it even when I only take the key as a column.

Does anyone have any idea? I tried to google this issue, but I only found issues people had where they tried to call functions where the functions were not defined. But in my SSAS project, I don't understand where this startIndex can come from.

Comment: If I were to guess, I would look for nulls or empty strings in your dimension.

Comment: @Keithl        Ah yes perhaps the error message has had me looking in the wrong direction. Will dig into that, thanks!